# homebrew: Failed to detect successful installation of [gazebo]

Tags: gazebo, rosdep, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had ROS Hydro installed and uninstalled in to install ROS Jade. During the install I'm getting an odd error. I'm being told that gazebo i already installed but that it can't be detected. How do I get around this?

```
 $ rosdep install --from-paths src
--ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y executing command [brew install gazebo] Warning: osrf/simulation/gazebo1-1.9.7 already installed ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install   homebrew: Failed to detect successful installation of [gazebo]
```

OS X El Capitan (10.11.3)

** EDIT **

```
$ brew tap
homebrew/python
homebrew/science
homebrew/versions
homebrew/x11
jlhonora/lsusb
osrf/simulation
ros/deps
totakke/openni


$ brew list | grep gazebo | xargs brew info
osrf/simulation/gazebo1: stable 1.9.7, HEAD
Gazebo robot simulator
http://gazebosim.org
/usr/local/Cellar/gazebo1/1.9.7 (738 files, 54.6M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation/blob/master/gazebo1.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: boost ✔, doxygen ✔, freeimage ✔, libtar ✔, ogre ✔, protobuf ✔, protobuf-c ✔, qt ✔, sdformat ✔, tbb ✔, tinyxml ✔
Optional: bullet ✔, ffmpeg ✘, gts ✘, player ✘, simbody ✔
==> Options
--with-bullet
    Build with bullet support
--with-ffmpeg
    Build with ffmpeg support
--with-gts
    Build with gts support
--with-player
    Build with player support
--with-simbody
    Build with simbody support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version

osrf/simulation/gazebo5: stable 5.2.1, HEAD
Gazebo robot simulator
http://gazebosim.org
/usr/local/Cellar/gazebo5/5.2.1 (962 files, 111.2M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation/blob/master/gazebo5.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: boost ✔, doxygen ✔, freeimage ✔, libtar ✔, ogre ✔, protobuf ✔, protobuf-c ✔, qt ✔, sdformat ✔, tbb ✔, tinyxml ✔
Recommended: bullet ✔, simbody ✔
Optional: dartsim/dart/dartsim4 ✘, ffmpeg ✘, gdal ✘, gts ✘, player ✘
==> Options
--with-dartsim4
    Build with dartsim4 support
--with-ffmpeg
    Build with ffmpeg support
--with-gdal
    Build with gdal support
--with-gts
    Build with gts support
--with-player
    Build with player support
--without-bullet
    Build without bullet support
--without-simbody
    Build without simbody support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228311/homebrew:-failed-to-detect-successful-installation-of-%5Bgazebo%5D/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-05**:
Can you add to your question the output of `brew tap` and `brew list | grep gazebo | xargs brew info`?

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-03-05**:
@William I added the outputs to the bottom of the question. Let me know if you need to see anything else. Also, I found that I can safely move to the next step and ros installs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably will have to uninstall "gazebo1" and install "gazebo". I'm not sure exactly how it got into that state, but `rosdep resolve gazebo` gives:

```
#homebrew
gazebo
```

So that should be the equivalent of `brew install gazebo`. If you're satisfied that you have gazebo installed you can also give the rosdep install line the extra argument `--skip-keys gazebo`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2016-05-03**:
I was facing the same issue and `brew uninstall gazebo1` and `brew uninstall gazebo5` and later `brew install gazebo` solved it. Thanks William.